# Which ISO file, vmlinuz and initrd.gz to use for installing CentOS from Multiboot USB?

Tags: centos, grub2, usb-drive

I have created a multiboot bootable USB with GRUB and used it to install Debian 8.1 successfully. A multiboot USB is one that contains the ISO images of multiple operating systems, with GRUB being used to choose which one to boot.

For Debian, it is a key that:

1. The Debian 8.1 ISO should be the type of hybrid. I downloaded it from
   http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/
2. The `vmlinuz` and `initrd.gz` files should be `hd-median` for debian-installer. I downloaded them from    http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/installer-i386/current/images/hd-media/

The `grub.cfg` file for installing Debian 8.1 is :

```
menuentry 'to install Debian 8.1 from usb' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set isofile="(hd0)/debian-8.1/debian-8.1-hybrid.iso"
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (hd0)/debian-8.1/vmlinuz
    initrd (hd0)/debian-8.1/initrd.gz
 }
```

Now, I want to add CentOS 7 to the same USB drive and be able to boot it from the GRUB menu. There three kinds of CentOS ISO:

1. DVD ISO
2. Everything ISO
3. Minimal ISO

There is no hybrid ISO for CentOS like there is for Debian. Which kind of ISO file and `vmlinuz`, `initrd.gz` files should I use to install CentOS from USB? How should I configure GRUB to boot the CentOS 7 ISO?

I have tested:

1. I downloaded `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveCD-1503.iso`
2. I mounted the ISO and copied `vmlinuz0` and `initrd0.img` from the `isolinux` directory
3. I created a `grub.cfg` entry as follows:

   ```
   menuentry 'to install centos7.1 from usb' {
       insmod part_msdos
       insmod ext2
       insmod ntfs
       set isofile="(hd0,0)/centos-7.1/CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveCD-1503.iso"
       loopback loop $isofile
       linux (hd0,0)/centos-7.1/vmlinuz0    
       initrd (hd0,0)/centos-7.1/initrd0.img
   }
   ```

I received the following error:

[image]

The USB HDD I'm using has a directory structure as follows:.

```
├── boot
│   └── grub
│       ├── fonts
│       │   └── unicode.pf2
│       ├── grub.cfg
│       ├── grubenv
│       ├── i386-pc
│       │   ├── 915resolution.mod
│       │   └── zfs.mod
│       └── locale
│           ├── ast.mo
│           ├── ca.mo
│           ├── da.mo
│           ├── vi.mo
│           ├── zh_CN.mo
│           └── zh_TW.mo
├── centos-7.1
│   ├── CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveCD-1503.iso
│   ├── initrd0.img
│   └── vmlinuz0
├── debian-8.1
│   ├── debian-8.1-hybrid.iso
│   ├── initrd.gz
│   └── vmlinuz
```

Many sub-directories deleted for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference where the vmlinuz file is you reference from the ISO's root, so your centos-7.1 directory is wrong.

To boot from an official ISO which has been marked as a live CD you will have to do some hacking.

First to identify what vmlinuz and initrd I would mount the iso image, and find the directory where the vmlinuz and initrd are. THAT is the directory you have to write in your grub.cfg after (hd0,0) (By the way, it should be **loop**, not (hd0,0)) substituting centos-7.1 I would also check its config scripts to see if some options are needed and add those options.

Anyway, you have a guide [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#CentOS)

Comment: please see the usb-hdd directories structure, my centos-7.1 directory isn't wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't have that structure, I would just have a folder called ISOs and inside that folder the iso file of the live CDs I want to boot from. You don't need the vmlinuz nor initrd, since they are inside the iso files. Just access them via `linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz $options` modify live by the right directory in your centos iso and check the options. Also check the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

The CentOS wiki has a [guide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey) to installing from USB that covers 6.5 and later (including 7.x). Have you tried those steps?

Basically, it involves writing the ISO image to a USB drive and booting from it. So, something like:

```
dd if=CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Where `/dev/sdb` is your flash drive.

That's slightly different from your Debian example, but you don't specify booting the ISO from GRUB is a requirement just "from USB". If that is the case @YoMismo's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217547/5186) has the information required.

Comment: My usb-hh is 16G,the dd command will delete everything on my disk,i have tried the dd way,it is rigth ,but i want to save my disk space,so l want to install centos with grub way, to write a right grub.cfg,and put centos iso on the usb-hdd, the other space can be used.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't 100% clear that was what you wanted to do. I've amended your question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the proper format of grub.cfg  should be the following:

```
menuentry "to install  CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-DVD" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    insmod ntfs
    set isofile='(hd0)/centos-7.1/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso'
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz noeject inst.stage2=hd:/dev/sdb:/centos-7.1/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso
    initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
}
```